# Inconsistency between sed and python regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, sed

*I apologize if this is published somewhere, but my cursory searching didn't find anything.*

While doing some Python programming I noticed that the following command:

```
re.sub("a*((ab)*)b", r"\1", "aabb")
```

returns the empty string. But an equivalent command in sed:

```
echo "aabb" | sed "s/a*\(\(ab\)*\)b/\1/"
```

returns `ab`.

It makes sense to me that the "a*" directive at the beginning of the python regex would match both `a`'s, causing "(ab)*" to match zero times, but I have no idea how sed comes up with `ab`. Does anybody know what the difference is between the two regex engines that causes this? I believe they both match stars greedily by default, but it occurred to me that sed might match from the right rather than the left. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Somewhere I read that "sed/awk use a DFA" and "python/perl/java use a NFA". It does change semantics with alternations (backtracking?) .. could this be related?

Comment: @pst: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but it seems like any backtracking-based approach would use a DFA; the effect of using an NFA would be to eliminate the need for backtracking, because all branches are examined simultaneously. So, I'd expect Perl/Python/Java/etc. to use a DFA. Is it possible that you read the opposite of what you wrote: maybe you read that sed/awk use an NFA and Perl/Python/Java etc. use a DFA?

Comment: @pst: And it *would* explain the observed behavior, if sed/awk use an NFA, and then choose whichever way of matching gave the longest match. In this case, letting `\(\(ab\)*\)` match `ab` produces a longer overall match, `aabb`, then having it match the empty string, since the latter would mean that the regex as a whole would only match `aab`.

Comment: @pst: Correction to my earlier comments: http://www.foo.be/docs/tpj/issues/vol1_2/tpj0102-0006.html uses the term "NFA" to describe a regex engine that does do backtracking, and "DFA" for a regex engine that does not. Now that I think about it, I guess that can make sense; an "NFA" engine makes a note-to-self "I made a nondeterministic decision here, so if I backtrack to this point, I should try a different branch", whereas a "DFA" engine pre-converts the NFA to a non-backtracking DFA by exploding the number of states. But that page also claims that sed and Perl both use NFA engines. :-/

Comment: @ruakh The expanded comments about NFA/DFA went over-my-head, but http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.htmlsays "The Pattern engine performs traditional NFA-based matching with ordered alternation as occurs in Perl 5.". I think "backtracking" was wrong and I should have said "longest match" at the start .. I am not sure where I saw the bit on sed/awk (another SO question?).

Comment: Almost looks like sed is doing an ungreedy match? If you were to make your pattern in python ungreedy you'd get the same result.

Comment: No, sed REs are greedy. It's just following POSIX and not stopping after it finds one match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting puzzle you've constructed. From what I've read, the regexp engines of both python and sed are based on Henry Spencer's regex library (as is perl's), which relies on backtracking. (Unfortunately I can't find the article I'm basing this on).

Anyway, this is **not** something that's supposed to be an implementation detail: Python's behavior goes against the POSIX standard, which requires REs to (a) match at the earliest possible point, and (b) match the longest possible string that starts at that point. (See [`man 7 regex`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/regex) (on Linux) for this and a whole lot more.)

To find the longest match, a backtracking ("NFA-type") regex engine must continue examining alternatives after it finds one match. So it's not surprising that the implementers cut corners. Obviously, python's behavior is non-conforming since it fails to find the longest match. According to the sed manual page, sed doesn't always conform either, "for performance reasons". But obviously it gets this case right.

Incidentally, your commands are not fully equivalent: `re.sub` will perform a substitution as many times as possible, while sed's `s/a/b/` will only perform it once.The sed version should have been:

```
echo "aabb" | sed "s/a*\(\(ab\)*\)b/\1/g"
```

This explains why we get the empty string in python: The RE matches `aab` the first time and the remaining `b` the second time, removing each part (since it's all matched by `a*` and the final `b` of the regexp). You can see this by the following variant:

```
>>> re.sub("a*((ab)*)b", r"X\1Y", "aabb")
'XYXY'
```

Comment: Perl does the same as Python in this case: `$ perl -E '$_ = "aabb"; s/a*((ab)*)b/<\1>/g; print $_, "\n";'` result `<><>` btw. non greedy `...s/a*?...` result `<ab>`.

Comment: So what? Plain `*` is greedy in all three engines. It's a coincidence that the non-greedy version gives the same result in this case.

Comment: Cool. FWIW, telling python to match once, so that the two commands are equivalent, doesn't seem affect whether the matching group is used (`re.sub("a*((ab)*)b","[\1]","aabb") -> "[]b"`), but that's a good point.

Comment: Exactly; it doesn't affect the way the RE is applied, but two substitutions are different than one. (But you must have used `re.sub("a*((ab)*)b", r"[\1]", "aabb", count=1)`; the command you cite actually matches twice, and doesn't return `"[]b"`)

Comment: Python's (and Java's, JavaScript's, .NET's, Perl's, PHP's, Ruby's and more) regex engines are not POSIX engines. The leftmost-longest rule does not apply.

Answer (score 4):

Both Python and sed are greedy by default but...
Python regex tries to evaluate from left to right in all circumstances, despite of it must do eventually a backtrace to the previous state if the branch being tried can not continue by matching.
Sed regex on the contrary are optimized before evaluating in order to prevent an unnecessary backtrace, by rewriting the regex to a more deterministic form. Therefore the combined optional pattern "aab" is probably tested before the plain "a" because the most specific possible string is tried first.

Python pattern matches the string "aabb" twice as "aab" + "b" (marked between "<>")

```
>>> re.sub("a*((ab)*)b", r"<\1>", "aabb")
'<><>'
```

while sed matches the whole "aabb" by one substitution:

```
$ echo "aabb" | sed "s/a*\(\(ab\)*\)b/<\1>/"
<ab>
```

Python regex backtrace algorithm is explained good in [regex howto - Repeating Things](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#repeating-things) in two paragraphs introduced by words "A step-by-step example...". It does IMO exactly what is described [regex docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax): "As the target string is scanned, REs separated by '|' **are tried from left to right**."

Demonstration

The order of "(|a|aa)" btw. "(aa|a|)" is respected by Python

```
>>> re.sub("(?:|a|aa)((ab)*)b", r"<\1>", "aabb")
'<ab>'
>>> re.sub("(?:aa|a|)((ab)*)b", r"<\1>", "aabb")
'<><>'
```

but this order is **ignored by sed** because sed optimizes regular expressions. Matching "aab" + "b" can be reproduced removing "a" option from the pattern.

```
$ echo "aabb" | sed "s/\(\|a\|aa\)\(\(ab\)*\)b/<\2>/g"
<ab>
$ echo "aabb" | sed "s/\(aa\|a\|\)\(\(ab\)*\)b/<\2>/g"
<ab>
$ echo "aabb" | sed "s/\(aa\|\)\(\(ab\)*\)b/<\2>/g"
<><>
```

---

**Edit**: I removed everything about DFA/NFA because I can not prove it from current texts.