# R vs sed regex greediness

Tags: regex, r, sed

I don't quite understand why this doesn't result in `"test"` and would appreciate an explanation:

```
a = "blah test"
sub('^.*(test|$)', '\\1', a)
# [1] ""
```

Compare it to the `sed` expression:

```
echo 'blah test' | sed -r 's/^.*(test|$)/\1/'
# test
echo 'blah blah' | sed -r 's/^.*(test|$)/\1/'
#
```

Fwiw, the following achieves what I want in R (and is equivalent to the above `sed` results):

```
sub('^.*(test)|^.*', '\\1', a)
```

Comment: @agstudy I'm trying to match either `test` or end of line - as you can see `sed` understands that logic. I don't understand why you say that `(test|$) == $`? I added an edit with what I want.

Comment: @agstudy to emphasize my not understanding what you wrote, try running `sub('(test|$)', 'bb', a)`, where R certainly doesn't interpret it to be the same as `sub('$', 'bb', a)`

Comment: Though this doesn't change the results, one thing to note that is R uses extended regular expressions and sed (4.2.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit) uses basic regular expressions by default. As I said, `echo 'blah test' | sed -r 's/^.*(test|$)/\1/')` produces the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The start of the `regex engine` matchs all the characters right upto the end of the string i.e **greedy** `.*`, then it tries to match `(test|$)`, i.e either the string literal 'test' or the end of the string. Since the first **greedy** match of `.*` matched all the characters, it `back-references` a character and then again tries to match `(test|$)`, here `$` matches the end of the string.

Causing your match result to be a `end of line character`

I think `sed` uses **POSIX NFA** which tries to find the longest match in a Alternation, which differs from `R`, which seems to use a **Traditional NFA**

Comment: thanks; am I misunderstanding smth about traditional vs POSIX NFA, since `(set|setvalue)` and `(setvalue|set)` match the exact same way in both `sed` and `R` as far as I can tell (testing matching on 'setvalue')...?

Comment: Though both seem to use NFA, there could be slight variations in their implementations, proving one faster than the other in some cases.

Also read
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100588/inconsistency-between-sed-and-python-regular-expressions

Answer (score 5):

You need to mark the `^.*` as [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

```
> sub('^.*?(test|$)', '\\1', "blah test")
[1] "test"
> sub('^.*?(test|$)', '\\1', "blah blah")
[1] ""
```

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich, I'm not sure what I mean. Maybe I mean _lazy_.

Comment: @GSee yes yu make the `.*` `lazy`.

Comment: @GSee thanks, this is certainly useful, it seems like `sed` has a different idea of laziness/greediness though, since the example from your link works the greedy way for `sed`: `echo "bbb <t1> ccc <t2>" | sed 's/<.*>/removed/'` results in `bbb removed`; I guess conditionals' greediness has different implementations.

Comment: Is there a sense in which one is "correct" and the other one isn't? From that link I got the impression that `sed` does it wrong?

Comment: *Lazy*, *non-greedy* and *reluctant* all mean the same thing in this context.  But *optional* doesn't apply, so I deleted that.